# R, Set dates as generic day and hour of week

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

Good day, i have a dataset with values for every hour of every day of the week for the past month, I want to compare the values of this week, with the values of the previous week and put them on a plot.
I have used the following code to create the date format;

```
WeekDate <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2018-09-19 0:00", tz="UTC"),
to=as.POSIXct("2018-09-25 23:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")
```

And

```
PreviousWeekDate <- seq(from=as.POSIXct("2018-09-12 0:00", tz="UTC"),
to=as.POSIXct("2018-09-18 23:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")
```

and I merged that with the values (we could use y1 = (0:167) and y2 = (1:168) as dummy values) I had.

I used plotly to get the charts

```
  plot_ly() %>%
add_lines(x = WeekDate, y = y1, name = "2018-09-19 to 2018-09-25") %>%
add_lines(x = PreviousWeekDate, y = y2, name = "2018-09-12 to 2018-09-19")
```

What I want to do is to get a plot like the following one;[Week plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLebU.png)

Instead of the one I get;[Non Overlapped Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1NCG.png)

In the X axis i want it to say; Monday HH:MM, so I can directly compare one value to another and so it indicates which time we are looking at. And I want them to overlap. Something like translating the dates to a generic Week, without the actual month/day.

I have not found anything, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest adding a variable to denote which week a given observation belongs to, and then using a rescaled x axis where all values mapped to current week, e.g. add 7 days to prior week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be cleaned up a little by hiding the "time_norm" data from the tooltip, but I think it does basically what you're looking for.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate); library(plotly)
df <- data_frame(
  time = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2018-09-12 0:00", tz="UTC"),
                  to=as.POSIXct("2018-09-25 23:00", tz="UTC"), by="hour")) %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "y") %>%
  mutate(week      = if_else(time > max(time) - ddays(7), "This week", "Last week"),
         time_norm = if_else(time > max(time) - ddays(7), time, time + ddays(7)))

ggplotly( 
  { 
  ggplot(df, aes(time_norm, y, color = week, label = norm)) +
  geom_line()
  }
```